# Equation using abs-sqrt-pow

Tags: c, math

I know java and now I am trying to learn C. I have a math problem and I tried to do it on C but I think I don't know if this part of my code is correct or not. The math exercise is

- If **|x|>1** then **f(x)=1.0 ÷ √(|x² − 1.0|)**.
- If **|x|=1** then it would be **f(x)=0**.
- Last case: if **|x|<1** then **f(x)=1.0 ÷ √(|1.0-x²|)**.

Here is my code:

```
for (x = a; x <= b; x = x + h) {
    while (x < b) {
        if (abs(x) > 1) {
            y = 1 / sqrt(pow(x, 2) - 1);
            printf("y= %d", y); 
        } else
        if (abs(x) == 1) {
            y = -9999;
            printf("y= %d", y);
        } else
        if (abs(x) < 1) {
            y = 1 / sqrt(1 - pow(x, 2));
            printf("y= %d", y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your inner while loop will be an infinite loop as you are not changing the value of x. Moreover, please state clearly what is the output that you are expecting and what output are you getting. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: no i dont want the result :D the only i care is if this i wrote is right :D

Comment: As I stated that the inner while loop might go into infinite loop so you must fix that up by incrementing the value of x accordingly.

Comment: where should i  change the value of x i didnt catch it.f you could explain it more i would be happy i am not so clever to catch it :)

Comment: See the inner while loop part - while(x<b) { .... }. This loop will continue forever if x< b initially. So you must increment the loop variable x accordingly.

Comment: you mean to put the x >b so that will ended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has an infinite loop: the `while` condition is constant as `x` is not modified in its body.  This `while` loop is actually redundant and should be removed.

You should move the code into a function definition and give the argument and return values the type `double`:

```
#include <math.h>

double f(double x) {
    if (fabs(x) > 1.0) {
        return 1.0 / sqrt(x * x - 1.0);
    } else
    if (fabs(x) == 1) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        return 1.0 / sqrt(1.0 - x * x);
    }
}
```

Use it in this loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_values(double a, double b, double h) {
    for (double x = a; x <= b; x = x + h) {
        printf("f(%g) = %g\n", x, f(x));
    }
}
```

As noted by Peter, the function `f(x)` can be further simplified into:

```
double f(double x) {
    if (fabs(x) == 1.0) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        return 1.0 / sqrt(fabs(1.0 - x * x));
    }
}
```

and using the ternary operator:

```
double f(double x) {
    return (fabs(x) == 1.0) ? 0.0 : 1.0 / sqrt(fabs(1.0 - x * x));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) Sorry for asking more but i cant see now the x=x+1.It should be somewhere?

Comment: now i catch it :D dont write anything i catch again thanks :D

Comment: Your function `f()` can be simplified even more to a one-liner:  `return (fabs(x) == 1.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0/sqrt(fabs(x*x - 1.0)));`